# Is it possible to change the state from a functional component in another function that is not inside my functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im learning React Native and im using the poke api to play with. I have my main app, with an image component to show the sprite of the pokemon when the user enters a number on my Text Input. This is what i have so far:

Main app:

```
export default function App() {
  const [numero, setNumero] = React.useState('');
  const [imagenURL, setImagenURL] = React.useState('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/items/poke-ball.png');

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={{fontSize:20, padding:20, textAlign:'center'}}>Ingrese un numero del pokémon a buscar!</Text>
      <TextInput
          style={{ width:'90%', height: 50, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, backgroundColor: '#fffff0', textAlign:'center', borderRadius: 20, borderWidth:5, margin:20}}
          onChangeText={(value) => setNumero(value)}
          value={numero}
          maxLength={20}
       />
      <Button onPress={()=> ConsultarPokemon(numero)}> 
        Ingresar 
      </Button> 
      <Image
        style={styles.img}
        source={{uri: imagenURL}}
      />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

This is how i fetch the value and get the pokemon object, i then use the SetImageURL to what the value of my pokemon's image should be.

```
const ConsultarPokemon = (num) =>{
  if (isNaN(num) || num == ""){
    Alert.alert('Ingreso incorrecto', 'Ingrese un numero');
  } else{
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${num}`)
    .then(function(response){
      response.json() //se convierte las respuesta en json, para que el nav lo entienda
      .then(function(pokemon){
        setImagenURL(pokemon.sprites.front_default);
      })
    })  
  }
}
```

But i get the warning: **Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0); Cant find variable setImageURL.**

Is it because im using the useState hook wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, all you have to do is add a parameter to `ConsultarPokemon` that accepts a setState function and pass `setImagenURL` when calling the function in your main component.

ConsultarPokemon:

```
const ConsultarPokemon = (num, setState) =>{
  if (isNaN(num) || num == ""){
    Alert.alert('Ingreso incorrecto', 'Ingrese un numero');
  } else{
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${num}`)
    .then(function(response){
      response.json() //se convierte las respuesta en json, para que el nav lo entienda
      .then(function(pokemon){
        setState(pokemon.sprites.front_default);
      })
    })  
  }
}
```

Main app:

```
    <Button onPress={()=> ConsultarPokemon(numero, setImagenURL)}>
```

Comment: that could work too! But i just copied and pasted my function inside my main app lol, i dont know why i put it outside! It now works and my pokemons are showing up :P

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass down the setImageUrl as a second parameter to the function ConsultarPokemon. If the ConsultarPokemon function would be nested inside App then you would not have to pass it as a prob, but right now the function does not know what is setImageUrl.
And also functions(ConslutarPokemon) should be written with small first letter and only components(App) with capital first letter - important for readability and compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it! i had to put my function INSIDE my main app. So now it looks like this, and it works :) my pokemons are finally showing up lol im so happy

```
export default function App() {
  const [numero, setNumero] = React.useState('');
  const [imagenURL, setImagenURL] = React.useState('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/items/poke-ball.png');

  const ConsultarPokemon = (num) =>{
    if (isNaN(num) || num == ""){
      Alert.alert('Ingreso incorrecto', 'Ingrese un numero');
    } else{
      fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${num}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(pokemon => {
        Alert.alert('ingreso al crear pokemon', pokemon.name); 
        setImagenURL(pokemon.sprites.front_default)
      }); 
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.texto}>Ingrese un numero del pokémon a buscar!</Text>
      <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={(value) => setNumero(value)}
          value={numero} // no need to use this.state.numero
          maxLength={20}
       />
      <Button onPress={()=> ConsultarPokemon(numero)}> 
        Ingresar 
      </Button> 
      <Image
        style={styles.img}
        source={{uri: imagenURL}}
      />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't understand... You solved it with this answer, but you accepted another answer?

Comment: yeah because i cant choose my own answer, but the other answer works too